# How can I nest objects from an array that have repeating values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got an array of objects for bus arrivals. The array has objects that have repeating properties but different times. I would like to nest the buses that come later into the bus that comes first. Also the array is ordered by arrival time.

```
[ 
   { Arrival, busId: "123", minToStop: 16, timeToStop: 957 },
   { Arrival, busId: "123", minToStop: 23, timeToStop: 1390 } 
]
```

Is there any nice and easy way to do it in javascript?

This is what I want to get

```
[ 
   { Arrival, busId: "123", minToStop: 16, timeToStop: 957, laterBuses: 
      [
         { Arrival, busId: "123", minToStop: 23, timeToStop: 1390 },
         { Arrival, busId: "123", minToStop: 30, timeToStop: 1820 }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: I would have an object with busIds as keys and the values are just an array of ordered objects. Similar to what you have but not nested because that adds unnecessary complication imo.

Comment: I tried looping through the array and comparing all object's but I couldn't figure out a way where I can compare all properties of all objects.

Comment: @Andy I want to list all buses that are comming first and add a little note at the bottom of the bus saying when's the next one comming

Comment: You could implement @Andy's suggestion and use `busId` as the key of the bus. You could then have `laterBuses` be an array of bus IDs.
Couldn't you just sort the array based on `timeToStop ` though?

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz the array is already sorted by `timeToStop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array to one value (a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)) and then [spread](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#spreadrest) the values of that map as new array:

```js
const busses = [
  { busId: '234', minToStop: 40, timeToStop: 1390 },
  { busId: '123', minToStop: 16, timeToStop: 957 },
  { busId: '123', minToStop: 23, timeToStop: 1490 },
  { busId: '234', minToStop: 17, timeToStop: 957 },
  { busId: '123', minToStop: 40, timeToStop: 1390 },
  { busId: '123', minToStop: 30, timeToStop: 1390 },
  { busId: '234', minToStop: 1, timeToStop: 1490 },
];
console.log([
  ...busses
    .sort((a, b) => a.minToStop - b.minToStop)
    .reduce((result, bus) => {
      const parentBus = result.get(bus.busId);
      const current = parentBus || {
        ...bus,
        laterBusses: [],
      };
      if (!!parentBus) {
        //only add to laterbusses if it's not the first bus found
        current.laterBusses.push(bus);
      }
      return result.set(current.busId, current);
    }, new Map())
    .values(),
]);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This solution will first sort the buses by `minToStop` and then by `busId`. It then iterates through the `buses` array and conditionally puts the bus at the top level of a `final` array or nested as you requested.

```js
const buses = [ 
   { busId: "234", minToStop: 40, timeToStop: 1390 },
   { busId: "123", minToStop: 16, timeToStop: 957 },
   { busId: "123", minToStop: 23, timeToStop: 1490 },
   { busId: "234", minToStop: 17, timeToStop: 957 },
   { busId: "123", minToStop: 30, timeToStop: 1390 },
   { busId: "234", minToStop: 1, timeToStop: 1490 } 
];

buses.sort((a,b) => a.minToStop - b.minToStop);
buses.sort((a,b) => a.busId > b.busId);

let formatted = [];

buses.forEach(bus => {
  if (
    formatted.length > 0 && 
    formatted[formatted.length - 1].busId === bus.busId
  ) {
    formatted[formatted.length - 1].laterBuses.push(bus);
  } else {
    bus.laterBuses = [];
    formatted.push(bus);
  }
});

console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: I need them nested inside the first bus objects laterBus array and removed from the main array